# JVM Crash: relationship with java.awt.Graphics?

Tags: java, graphics, crash, jvm, awt

I encounter problems with crashing jvms (Swing application). After some research I noticed that the java.awt.Graphics is always present in the java frame stacktrace. This is one of the crash reports:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x5d46533d, pid=1892, tid=3976
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_74-b02) (build 1.8.0_74-b02)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.74-b02 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0xe533d]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x2613dc00):  JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_vm, id=3976, stack(0x27730000,0x27780000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0xff808084

Registers:
EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x2613dc00, ECX=0x10511490, EDX=0xff808080
ESP=0x2777dd74, EBP=0x2777dd90, ESI=0x2777de00, EDI=0x32c64228
EIP=0x5d46533d, EFLAGS=0x00010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x2777dd74)
0x2777dd74:   32c64228 2777de00 2613dd40 2613dc00
0x2777dd84:   00000000 26b7b168 00000052 00000000
0x2777dd94:   5f824983 2613dd40 2669ae9c 00000000
0x2777dda4:   00000014 00000014 0000003f 5f842290
0x2777ddb4:   2613dd40 32c64228 2777de00 2613dc00
0x2777ddc4:   00000014 2777dec8 10afad18 32c64228
0x2777ddd4:   2613dd40 5f914828 ffc0c0c0 2613dc00
0x2777dde4:   2777eaec 2777de18 5d457326 2613dc00 

Instructions: (pc=0x5d46533d)
0x5d46531d:   12 fb ff 83 c4 04 eb 06 ff 83 b4 01 00 00 8b 45
0x5d46532d:   10 85 c0 74 03 c6 00 00 8b 4d 0c 8b 09 8b 51 04
0x5d46533d:   8b 42 04 3d 00 00 00 c0 7c 19 c1 f8 08 25 ff 00
0x5d46534d:   00 00 83 f8 07 74 05 83 f8 0b 75 07 b8 04 00 00 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EBX=0x2613dc00 is a thread
ECX=
[error occurred during error reporting (printing register info), id 0xc0000005]

Stack: [0x27730000,0x27780000],  sp=0x2777dd74,  free space=311k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0xe533d]
C  [awt.dll+0x4983]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 4040  sun.java2d.loops.DrawLine.DrawLine(Lsun/java2d/SunGraphics2D;Lsun/java2d/SurfaceData;IIII)V (0 bytes) @ 0x01f06718 [0x01f06690+0x88]
J 63107 C1 sun.java2d.pipe.LoopPipe.drawLine(Lsun/java2d/SunGraphics2D;IIII)V (46 bytes) @ 0x01fb39fc [0x01fb3990+0x6c]
J 63617 C1 sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawLine(IIII)V (74 bytes) @ 0x01d0b388 [0x01d0b330+0x58]
j  javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.paintContentBorderTopEdge(Ljava/awt/Graphics;IIIIII)V+111
j  nl.pharmapartners.lib.client.model.ClosableTabbedPane$CustomFontTitleTabbedPaneUI.paintContentBorder(Ljava/awt/Graphics;II)V+332
j  javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;Ljavax/swing/JComponent;)V+63
J 3232 C1 javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(Ljava/awt/Graphics;Ljavax/swing/JComponent;)V (36 bytes) @ 0x01cab548 [0x01cab480+0xc8]
J 2690 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (44 bytes) @ 0x02066ca4 [0x02066c30+0x74]
J 2684 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (409 bytes) @ 0x02062df8 [0x02062b90+0x268]
J 28750 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (669 bytes) @ 0x02021cc0 [0x020214e0+0x7e0]
J 2684 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (409 bytes) @ 0x02062e50 [0x02062b90+0x2c0]
J 28750 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (669 bytes) @ 0x02021cc0 [0x020214e0+0x7e0]
j  javax.swing.JSplitPane.paintChildren(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V+2
J 2684 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (409 bytes) @ 0x02062e50 [0x02062b90+0x2c0]
J 28750 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (669 bytes) @ 0x02021cc0 [0x020214e0+0x7e0]
J 2684 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (409 bytes) @ 0x02062e50 [0x02062b90+0x2c0]
j  javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Ljava/awt/Graphics;IIIIII)V+41
J 987 C1 javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Ljavax/swing/JComponent;Ljava/awt/Image;Ljava/awt/Graphics;IIII)V (294 bytes) @ 0x01dd98e4 [0x01dd97a0+0x144]
J 4508 C1 javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Ljavax/swing/JComponent;Ljavax/swing/JComponent;Ljava/awt/Graphics;IIII)Z (189 bytes) @ 0x01f4ae78 [0x01f4ab50+0x328]
J 9911 C1 javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(Ljavax/swing/JComponent;Ljavax/swing/JComponent;Ljava/awt/Graphics;IIII)Z (235 bytes) @ 0x01db67c4 [0x01db6470+0x354]
J 10302 C1 javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Ljavax/swing/JComponent;Ljavax/swing/JComponent;Ljava/awt/Graphics;IIII)V (93 bytes) @ 0x01d1cc9c [0x01d1cac0+0x1dc]
J 2869 C1 javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(IIII)V (891 bytes) @ 0x01c7747c [0x01c76970+0xb0c]
J 7134 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(IIII)V (155 bytes) @ 0x01cc6eac [0x01cc6c70+0x23c]
J 10298 C1 javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run()Ljava/lang/Void; (278 bytes) @ 0x01d1d34c [0x01d1d220+0x12c]
J 10297 C1 javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run()Ljava/lang/Object; (5 bytes) @ 0x01dda360 [0x01dda340+0x20]
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J 910  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; (0 bytes) @ 0x01dc4f87 [0x01dc4f20+0x67]
J 963 C1 javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Ljava/util/Map;)V (196 bytes) @ 0x01dd3a3c [0x01dd3660+0x3dc]
j  javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions()V+46
j  javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions()V+73
j  javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(Ljavax/swing/RepaintManager;)V+1
j  javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run()V+37
J 4659 C1 java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch()V (69 bytes) @ 0x01fc84dc [0x01fc83f0+0xec]
J 5364 C1 java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V (149 bytes) @ 0x01d8d610 [0x01d8d150+0x4c0]
J 2279 C1 java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Void; (60 bytes) @ 0x01fd78dc [0x01fd7880+0x5c]
J 2278 C1 java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Object; (5 bytes) @ 0x01fd7660 [0x01fd7640+0x20]
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J 910  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; (0 bytes) @ 0x01dc4f87 [0x01dc4f20+0x67]
J 2255 C1 java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V (80 bytes) @ 0x01fcfaf8 [0x01fcf8f0+0x208]
J 5334 C1 nl.pharmapartners.lib.client.application.waitcursor.WaitCursorEventQueue.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V (125 bytes) @ 0x01ccc9c4 [0x01ccc7d0+0x1f4]
J 2091 C1 java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(I)V (295 bytes) @ 0x01f910d8 [0x01f90a40+0x698]
J 6652% C1 java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/EventFilter;)V (47 bytes) @ 0x0206fb6c [0x0206fac0+0xac]
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/Component;)V+11
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(ILjava/awt/Conditional;)V+4
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Ljava/awt/Conditional;)V+3
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run()V+9
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x24225400 JavaThread "Keep-Alive-Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4320, stack(0x35bd0000,0x35c20000)]
  0x26975000 JavaThread "URL-Loader-72" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6532, stack(0x38110000,0x38160000)]
  0x26975400 JavaThread "GhostBuster" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6140, stack(0x2df10000,0x2df60000)]
  0x26861800 
[error occurred during error reporting (printing all threads), id 0xc0000005]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 def new generation   total 89088K, used 6158K [0x03c00000, 0x09ca0000, 0x0e6a0000)
  eden space 79232K,   7% used [0x03c00000, 0x04203ad8, 0x08960000)
  from space 9856K,   0% used [0x08960000, 0x08960000, 0x09300000)
  to   space 9856K,   0% used [0x09300000, 0x09300000, 0x09ca0000)
 tenured generation   total 197704K, used 118620K [0x0e6a0000, 0x1a7b2000, 0x23c00000)
   the space 197704K,  59% used [0x0e6a0000, 0x15a772a8, 0x15a77400, 0x1a7b2000)
 Metaspace       used 50630K, capacity 51679K, committed 52352K, reserved 52608K

Card table byte_map: [0x23c00000,0x23d10000] byte_map_base: 0x23be2000

Polling page: 0x00280000

CodeCache: size=32768Kb used=5504Kb max_used=6131Kb free=27263Kb
 bounds [0x01bd0000, 0x021f0000, 0x03bd0000]
 total_blobs=3390 nmethods=2872 adapters=446
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 4725.226 Thread 0x241cfc00 64404             sun.awt.image.SunVolatileImage::createGraphics (27 bytes)
Event: 4725.228 Thread 0x241cfc00 nmethod 64404 0x01cf76c8 code [0x01cf7800, 0x01cf79c0]
Event: 4725.228 Thread 0x241cfc00 64405             sun.awt.image.SunVolatileImage::getForeground (19 bytes)
Event: 4725.229 Thread 0x241cfc00 nmethod 64405 0x01d5f548 code [0x01d5f650, 0x01d5f75c]
Event: 4725.229 Thread 0x241cfc00 64406             sun.awt.image.SunVolatileImage::getBackground (19 bytes)
Event: 4725.230 Thread 0x241cfc00 nmethod 64406 0x01d5f348 code [0x01d5f450, 0x01d5f4fc]
Event: 4725.230 Thread 0x241cfc00 64407             sun.awt.image.SunVolatileImage::getFont (43 bytes)
Event: 4725.230 Thread 0x241cfc00 nmethod 64407 0x01f18e08 code [0x01f18f20, 0x01f19068]
Event: 4725.785 Thread 0x241cfc00 64408             com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherBlockChaining::decrypt (102 bytes)
Event: 4725.786 Thread 0x241cfc00 nmethod 64408 0x0205ab08 code [0x0205ac30, 0x0205ae58]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 4623.874 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=159 (full 5):
 def new generation   total 58752K, used 58752K [0x03c00000, 0x07bb0000, 0x0e6a0000)
  eden space 52288K, 100% used [0x03c00000, 0x06f10000, 0x06f10000)
  from space 6464K, 100% used [0x07560000, 0x07bb0000, 0x07bb0000)
  to   space 6464K,   0% used [0x06f10000, 0x06f10000, 0x07560000)
 tenured generation   total 130284K, used 116841K [0x0e6a0000, 0x165db000, 0x23c00000)
   the space 130284K,  89% used [0x0e6a0000, 0x158ba5a8, 0x158ba600, 0x165db000)
 Metaspace       used 51056K, capacity 52219K, committed 52224K, reserved 52608K
Event: 4623.892 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=160 (full 5):
 def new generation   total 58752K, used 1391K [0x03c00000, 0x07bb0000, 0x0e6a0000)
  eden space 52288K,   0% used [0x03c00000, 0x03c00000, 0x06f10000)
  from space 6464K,  21% used [0x06f10000, 0x0706bfe0, 0x07560000)
  to   space 6464K,   0% used [0x07560000, 0x07560000, 0x07bb0000)
 tenured generation   total 130284K, used 123276K [0x0e6a0000, 0x165db000, 0x23c00000)
   the space 130284K,  94% used [0x0e6a0000, 0x15f03020, 0x15f03200, 0x165db000)
 Metaspace       used 51056K, capacity 52219K, committed 52224K, reserved 52608K
}
Event: 4675.482 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=160 (full 5):
 def new generation   total 58752K, used 53679K [0x03c00000, 0x07bb0000, 0x0e6a0000)
  eden space 52288K, 100% used [0x03c00000, 0x06f10000, 0x06f10000)
  from space 6464K,  21% used [0x06f10000, 0x0706bfe0, 0x07560000)
  to   space 6464K,   0% used [0x07560000, 0x07560000, 0x07bb0000)
 tenured generation   total 130284K, used 123276K [0x0e6a0000, 0x165db000, 0x23c00000)
   the space 130284K,  94% used [0x0e6a0000, 0x15f03020, 0x15f03200, 0x165db000)
 Metaspace       used 51056K, capacity 52219K, committed 52224K, reserved 52608K
Event: 4675.494 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=161 (full 5):
 def new generation   total 58752K, used 2901K [0x03c00000, 0x07bb0000, 0x0e6a0000)
  eden space 52288K,   0% used [0x03c00000, 0x03c00000, 0x06f10000)
  from space 6464K,  44% used [0x07560000, 0x07835750, 0x07bb0000)
  to   space 6464K,   0% used [0x06f10000, 0x06f10000, 0x07560000)
 tenured generation   total 130284K, used 123276K [0x0e6a0000, 0x165db000, 0x23c00000)
   the space 130284K,  94% used [0x0e6a0000, 0x15f03020, 0x15f03200, 0x165db000)
 Metaspace       used 51056K, capacity 52219K, committed 52224K, reserved 52608K
}
Event: 4707.228 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=161 (full 5):
 def new generation   total 58752K, used 55189K [0x03c00000, 0x07bb0000, 0x0e6a0000)
  eden space 52288K, 100% used [0x03c00000, 0x06f10000, 0x06f10000)
  from space 6464K,  44% used [0x07560000, 0x07835750, 0x07bb0000)
  to   space 6464K,   0% used [0x06f10000, 0x06f10000, 0x07560000)
 tenured generation   total 130284K, used 123276K [0x0e6a0000, 0x165db000, 0x23c00000)
   the space 130284K,  94% used [0x0e6a0000, 0x15f03020, 0x15f03200, 0x165db000)
 Metaspace       used 51067K, capacity 52234K, committed 52352K, reserved 52608K
Event: 4707.244 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=162 (full 5):
 def new generation   total 58752K, used 4167K [0x03c00000, 0x07bb0000, 0x0e6a0000)
  eden space 52288K,   0% used [0x03c00000, 0x03c00000, 0x06f10000)
  from space 6464K,  64% used [0x06f10000, 0x07321f00, 0x07560000)
  to   space 6464K,   0% used [0x07560000, 0x07560000, 0x07bb0000)
 tenured generation   total 130284K, used 123276K [0x0e6a0000, 0x165db000, 0x23c00000)
   the space 130284K,  94% used [0x0e6a0000, 0x15f03020, 0x15f03200, 0x165db000)
 Metaspace       used 51067K, capacity 52234K, committed 52352K, reserved 52608K
}
Event: 4717.322 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=162 (full 5):
 def new generation   total 58752K, used 56455K [0x03c00000, 0x07bb0000, 0x0e6a0000)
  eden space 52288K, 100% used [0x03c00000, 0x06f10000, 0x06f10000)
  from space 6464K,  64% used [0x06f10000, 0x07321f00, 0x07560000)
  to   space 6464K,   0% used [0x07560000, 0x07560000, 0x07bb0000)
 tenured generation   total 130284K, used 123276K [0x0e6a0000, 0x165db000, 0x23c00000)
   the space 130284K,  94% used [0x0e6a0000, 0x15f03020, 0x15f03200, 0x165db000)
 Metaspace       used 51070K, capacity 52237K, committed 52352K, reserved 52608K
Event: 4717.343 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=163 (full 5):
 def new generation   total 58752K, used 6464K [0x03c00000, 0x07bb0000, 0x0e6a0000)
  eden space 52288K,   0% used [0x03c00000, 0x03c00000, 0x06f10000)
  from space 6464K, 100% used [0x07560000, 0x07bb0000, 0x07bb0000)
  to   space 6464K,   0% used [0x06f10000, 0x06f10000, 0x07560000)
 tenured generation   total 130284K, used 125672K [0x0e6a0000, 0x165db000, 0x23c00000)
   the space 130284K,  96% used [0x0e6a0000, 0x1615a0e8, 0x1615a200, 0x165db000)
 Metaspace       used 51070K, capacity 52237K, committed 52352K, reserved 52608K
}
Event: 4724.310 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=163 (full 5):
 def new generation   total 58752K, used 58752K [0x03c00000, 0x07bb0000, 0x0e6a0000)
  eden space 52288K, 100% used [0x03c00000, 0x06f10000, 0x06f10000)
  from space 6464K, 100% used [0x07560000, 0x07bb0000, 0x07bb0000)
  to   space 6464K,   0% used [0x06f10000, 0x06f10000, 0x07560000)
 tenured generation   total 130284K, used 125672K [0x0e6a0000, 0x165db000, 0x23c00000)
   the space 130284K,  96% used [0x0e6a0000, 0x1615a0e8, 0x1615a200, 0x165db000)
 Metaspace       used 51070K, capacity 52237K, committed 52352K, reserved 52608K
Event: 4724.610 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=164 (full 6):
 def new generation   total 89088K, used 0K [0x03c00000, 0x09ca0000, 0x0e6a0000)
  eden space 79232K,   0% used [0x03c00000, 0x03c00000, 0x08960000)
  from space 9856K,   0% used [0x08960000, 0x08960000, 0x09300000)
  to   space 9856K,   0% used [0x09300000, 0x09300000, 0x09ca0000)
 tenured generation   total 197704K, used 118620K [0x0e6a0000, 0x1a7b2000, 0x23c00000)
   the space 197704K,  59% used [0x0e6a0000, 0x15a772a8, 0x15a77400, 0x1a7b2000)
 Metaspace       used 50630K, capacity 51679K, committed 52352K, reserved 52608K
}

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 4717.079 Thread 0x26863800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x06a128f0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u74\6087\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 4718.079 Thread 0x26863800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x0446bd70) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u74\6087\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 4719.079 Thread 0x26863800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x0446bfa8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u74\6087\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 4720.079 Thread 0x26863800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x0446c1e0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u74\6087\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 4721.079 Thread 0x26863800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x0446c418) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u74\6087\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 4722.079 Thread 0x26863800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x055625a0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u74\6087\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 4723.079 Thread 0x26863800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x055627d8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u74\6087\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 4724.079 Thread 0x2641a400 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x06e74ed8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u74\6087\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 4724.079 Thread 0x26863800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x05562a10) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u74\6087\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 4725.079 Thread 0x26863800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x041e1280) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u74\6087\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]

Events (10 events):
Event: 4724.637 Thread 0x241cfc00 flushing nmethod 0x0205ab08
Event: 4724.637 Thread 0x241cfc00 flushing nmethod 0x0205ad08
Event: 4724.637 Thread 0x241cfc00 flushing nmethod 0x02065fc8
Event: 4724.638 Thread 0x241cfc00 flushing nmethod 0x021d0a08
Event: 4725.787 Thread 0x241cfc00 flushing nmethod 0x01cf74c8
Event: 4725.787 Thread 0x24225400 Thread added: 0x24225400
Event: 4725.787 Thread 0x241cfc00 flushing nmethod 0x01db0c48
Event: 4725.787 Thread 0x241cfc00 flushing nmethod 0x01db0e08
Event: 4725.793 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 4725.793 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
```

I would like to know if you have seen this kind of crash before, and if so, I'm very interested in how you approached this issue.

Also all tips and hints are welcome ;)

Thanks in advance, 
Daan

Comment: First, update your JRE.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse Kayaman, I also considered to first upgrade the jre to the latest version. However I'm also curious what causes this kind of crash as I cannot find anything related on the internet.

Comment: You cannot find anything on the internet related to a program crashing on Windows? How hard did you look...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this problem is solved after updating the jre to the latest release version: 1.8.0u121. There are no reported crashes since the application is running on the jvm of the latest jre.